# Collision check between vectors - moving vectors - HTML, JS, P5

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

I have created the collision check function for my player to every time when the object (in this case vector - circle) touches the player (also a vector - circle) the game is over.

I have managed to create a logic and there is a collision check working, however it's not calculating the actual distance between elements (instead of ending game when they actually touch its ending when they are some distance from each other.

Both objects are moving - obstacle is moving x+=6 and the player is following the coursor so the speed varies.

I have tried adjusting distance slightly and I have managed to end the game when the x of obstacle is touch x of the player but could not managed actually to when boarders touch. I attach the code I have below;

```
    class Player {
    constructor(x, y, r) {
    this.pos = createVector(x, y);
    this.r = r;
    this.vel = createVector(500, 500);
    this.mag = 3;
    this.velLerp = 0.1;
  }

  update() {
    let mouse = createVector(mouseX - width / 2, 
    mouseY - height / 2);
    mouse.setMag(this.mag);
    this.vel.lerp(mouse, this.velLerp);
    this.pos.add(this.vel);

  collisionCheck(obstacle) {
    let d = p5.Vector.dist(this.pos, obstacle.pos);

    if (d < this.r + obstacle.r) {
     console.log("GAME OVER");
     return true;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am not using any sprites, the player is just a circle with a stroke(1) around it. Obstacle is also a circle with a stroke(1) surrounding it. I've meant like as soon as the strokes are touching then the game is over. P5 is drawing elements 60 times per second so maybe that is an issue.

Comment: hello, could you please post the code for your update loop? My guess would be that your  position update and collision checking are not in the right order. Basically, you would advance the motion, then check for the collision and either react to the collision or set new positions and repeat.

Comment: thanks to both of you for the reply! what would be the potential solution?

Comment: when I chane the collision check to instead (d < this.r + obstacle.r ) to (d < this.r ) it always seem to end the game if it touches the x of the obstacle - I need basically that but when it touches the stroke. I forgot to mention that the obstacles are randomly sizez (as there is a lot of them alway moving from left side of the canvas to the right). It seem to work when I set to touch the x of the obstacle but not the x + obstacle.r

Comment: Actually I don't under stand what you want. If `d < this.r + obstacle.r` the game is over. If `d >= this.r + obstacle.r` the game goes on. So what is the issue? You have to ensure that  `collisionCheck` is called at the right moment. After the positions of the objects have been computed and the objects have been drawn. Most likely you don't draw the last position of the objects respectively the game is over befor the final refresh.

Comment: My bad, are you able to provide me with the code that you have just posted? I think I was checking something incorrectly. I've just started coding and my code is quiet messy :D

Comment: Instead of just checking if a < b, try a<=b.
Do leave a link of your code so we can test by trial and error too.

Comment: Ive tried a <= b instead but still the same issue. Sure, what is the best way to provide you with the link for the code?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is caused by the fact that the movement of the circles is 3 (`this.mag`) pixel. You just get the exact point of contact by chance. Most time they are intersecting.
If a collision is detected, change the player's position slightly by an offset of `this.r + obstacle.r - d`:

```js
collisionCheck(obstacle) {
    let d = p5.Vector.dist(this.pos, obstacle.pos);

    if (d < this.r + obstacle.r) {
        
        let shift = p5.Vector.sub(this.pos, obstacle.pos);    
        shift.setMag(this.r + obstacle.r - d);
        this.pos.add(shift);

        console.log("GAME OVER");
        return true;
    }
}
```